# Google matrix - count distance between origin and destinations

Tags: swift, google-maps, swift3

I am trying to build request for google matrix service which will return distances between origin point and destinations.

Following : [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

Can not figure out how to build correct request.

```
SUCCESS: {
    "destination_addresses" =     (
    );
    "origin_addresses" =     (
    );
    rows =     (
    );
    status = "INVALID_REQUEST";
}

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&destinations%5B%5D=30.37577%2C-81.7837&destinations%5B%5D=26.89648%2C-82.00874&destinations%5B%5D=30.48638%2C-84.42159&destinations%5B%5D=35.11241%2C-80.95421&destinations%5B%5D=33.82343%2C-84.12118&destinations%5B%5D=33.67012%2C-78.93803&destinations%5B%5D=39.87034%2C-82.94822&destinations%5B%5D=42.14669%2C-87.83312&destinations%5B%5D=42.65981%2C-84.55101&destinations%5B%5D=39.87016%2C-82.9482&destinations%5B%5D=39.86784%2C-82.94884&destinations%5B%5D=39.87014%2C-82.94824&destinations%5B%5D=39.87021%2C-82.94826&destinations%5B%5D=42.67464%2C-82.83249&destinations%5B%5D=39.87025%2C-82.94812&destinations%5B%5D=39.87049%2C-82.94807&destinations%5B%5D=39.87057%2C-82.94829&destinations%5B%5D=40.43237%2C-74.48872&destinations%5B%5D=39.96912%2C-82.99415&destinations%5B%5D=40.44534%2C-74.41769&destinations%5B%5D=40.4453%2C-74.41779&destinations%5B%5D=41.28482%2C-72.93002&destinations%5B%5D=40.44524%2C-74.41776&destinations%5B%5D=40.44559%2C-74.41811&destinations%5B%5D=42.12788%2C-75.97026&destinations%5B%5D=40.44576%2C-74.41788&destinations%5B%5D=40.69494%2C-74.09928&destinations%5B%5D=40.76857%2C-73.73745&destinations%5B%5D=40.4856%2C-74.39982&destinations%5B%5D=30.26164%2C-98.8715&destinations%5B%5D=39.95258%2C-82.90484&destinations%5B%5D=32.69126%2C-96.24597&destinations%5B%5D=29.48223%2C-98.34786&destinations%5B%5D=32.82934%2C-97.03087&destinations%5B%5D=32.8292%2C-97.03081&key=NOPE_THATS_MY_KEY&origins=37.6724723880042%2C-90.4441829064476
```

The way I build the destinations array :

```
func createDestinationsArray(annotations: [MyAnnotation]) -> [String] {
        var destinations: [String] = []
        var destination: String!

        for annotation in annotations {
            destination = "\(annotations.lat),\(annotations.lon)"
            destinations.append(destination)
        }

        return destinations
    }
```

And the request :

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.cnoon.distance-queue", qos: .utility, attributes: .concurrent)


 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: ["origins" : origins, "destinations" : destinations, "key" : apiKey]).response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: { response in 
 ...
})
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs clearly show that you should have `|` as separating characters between the elements of your arrays. Also, you append **destinations** in front of each coordinate pair, which is clearly wrong if you look at the docs. You have two options. Either create your destinations and origins arrays as strings on the first place, containing the separators or later join the arrays into strings with the separator. Since as far as I can tell, you won't need your arrays for anything but the network request, I think generating a string directly is the more optimal solution.

```
func createDestinationsArray(annotations: [MyAnnotation]) -> String {
    return annotations.map({ return "\($0.latitude),\($0.longitude)" }).joined(separator: "|")
}
```

Comment: OK, so best solution would be create a string instead of array ? Because for each index from array of distances it is going to add to the request destinations.... destinations... etc ? Like its now ?

Comment: Yes, Alamofire encodes arrays differently than what Google Maps expects. And you don't need that array of strings for anything else than the request, so it's also more efficient to just generate and return the String itself from your createDestinationsArray function.

Comment: Shorter version: `return annotations.map({ return "\($0.latitude),\($0.longitude)" }).joined(separator: "|")`. Change func return type to `String`, not `[String]`

Comment: @Scriptable thanks for the input, that's an even better solution, I have updated my answer. I realised as well that I forgot to change the return type, so updated that too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Appreciate !